# Angular 2 Router: Cannot match any routes

Tags: node.js, angular, angular2-routing

When trying to load localhost:3000/verifyemail in my browser, I receive the error:

> Error: Cannot match any routes

I've read through the other SO questions on this, and have verified the following:

- Angular2: 2.3.1 uses Path Location Strategy by default, and I haven't changed it. I prefer not to use Hash Location Strategy
- I've configured my Nodejs server for HTML5 pushState (server.js is below)

  ```
  // Parsers for POST data
  app.use(bodyParser.json());
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

  // Point static path to dist
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));

  // Get API routes
  const api = require('./src/server/routes/api.js');

  // Set api routes
  app.use('/api', api);

  // Catch all other routes and return the index file
  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
  });

  const port = process.env.PORT || '3000';
  app.set('port', port);

  const server = http.createServer(app);
  server.listen(port, () => console.log(`API running on localhost:${port}`));
  ```
- I have `<base href="/">` at the top of my `<head>` in my index.html
- I have default and catch-all routes set

  ```
  const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'home',
      outlet: 'full-page',
      component: DefaultLandingPageComponent
    },

    { path: 'verifyemail',
      outlet: 'full-page',
      component: EmailVerificationComponent
    },

    { path: '',
      redirectTo: '/home',
      pathMatch: 'full'
    },

    { path: '**',
      outlet: 'full-page',
      component: DefaultLandingPageComponent
    }
   ];
  ```
- I've imported the router module into my app.module.ts, and included a router outlet in my app.component.html file

  ```
  //in app.module.ts:
  @NgModule({
    ...
    imports: [
      ...
      RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
    ]
    ...
    });

  //in app.component.html
  import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
  ```

Thanks a lot to whoever can give me a hand with this!

**Update 1**
I've removed all names from routes and the router outlet, thanks to Günter Zöchbauer's observation in the comments below

**Update 2**
Everything works as expected on localhost:4200/verifyemail, which is run via `ng serve`.
Problem persists when using localhost:3000/verifyemail, which is run via `node server.js`

Answer (score 1):

Each route needs a route that adds a component to an unnamed outlet.
Named outlets can only be used in addition to an unnamed outlet, not instead of.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help - that probably was a problem, but it's still not working. I removed the name property from the routes and from the router outlet, which now reads `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`. The server reload is working - if I change res.sendFile to any other file besides index.html, it will do so properly. The problem is when it gets redirects to index.html and then can't find any routes

Comment: Sorry, can't help you with node.js server settings.

Comment: Thanks - the server seems to be working properly, so I think the problem is on the angular side. Does anything else in my angular code stick out as maybe being a problem? Appreciate your help

Comment: if you use `RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {useHash: true})` and it still doesn't work, then it's an Angular code issue, otherwise it's a server issue.

Comment: Looks like we have an angular issue then - I replaced `RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)` with `RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {useHash: true})` and I receive the same error

Comment: I see. But I don't see anything wrong in your route configuration. Perhaps you can try to reproduce in a Plunker? (Plunker only work with HashLocationStrategy)

Comment: I assume you removed the name from **all** routes and router-outlets, your question doesn't reflect that yet.

Comment: Yeah, I removed name from all routes and router-outlets (and provided an update in the original question). I'm working on the plunker. Thanks again for the help

Comment: Plunker provides a ready-to-use Angular2 template (in case you don't know yet ;-) ) - just use the `New` button and choose the template.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135597/discussion-between-mangi1-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Comment: Here's the plunker. Thanks: https://embed.plnkr.co/9iivKaF3O8qFDngpEK8C/

Comment: I just saw your update. If it depends on what server you use, then it's rather unlikely that the issue is caused by the Angular2 app.

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right. I'm not sure if you're supposed to have one server for the angular2 app (the front end), and a separate server for the backend. I'll do some research and report back in case anyone else is running into this. Anyway, thanks for taking the time to help me - really appreciate it.

Comment: frontend-server and backend-server can be the same server, it just needs to behave properly ;-)